# Android WakeLock not working on first run

Tags: android, android-studio, wakelock

I have implemented wakelock in my app with below code:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

I want to prevent screen from going off when the user is in my app. The weird thing is , on first run of the application(right after install) it doesn't work and screen goes off, However after that if I close the application and run it again, wakelock works and prevents the app from going off.
I noticed that in the first time I get this error in my log:

```
WakeLock finalized while still held: MyWakelockTag
```

But in the next runs I don't get this error and everything works.

I don't get what causes this problem on the first run and I'll appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Show me your whole code, because if there is an issue with the mentioned code, it'll not work the second time. There is some issue with its positioning. Edit your question put the whole activity to find out the issue.

Comment: have added this permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: @SyedDaniyalNasir Thanks , I'm sure my code calls on each run, but I noticed that in the first run I get this error : WakeLock finalized while still held: MyWakelockTag
but I don't get it in the next runs

Comment: @SohailZahid Thanks , yes I have added that permission

Answer (score 0):

Ok I believe I found the problem.

The WakeLock is reference counted. That means that if a second acquire() happens it will just bump the reference count. Every call to acquire() needs to be protected by a call to isHeld() as in:

```
if ((keepScreenOn != null) && (keepScreenOn.isHeld() == false)) {
keepScreenOn.acquire();
}
```

I had assumed that acquire() on a lock I held did nothing so multiple acquire() calls caused the problem. Since the reference count is not zero the GC throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting in the first run of the application was :

```
WakeLock finalized while still held: MyWakelockTag
```

The solution was to add this line in onDestroy :

```
if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
 wakeLock.release();
}
```